# how to set status header to 200 in wordpress theme / plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently working on a Wordpress auction plugin. The plugin stores item in a separate table. I have successfully created the plugin and is working as expected (in the admin area).

Now I am trying to build a theme that will utilise the plugin. I need to display all the auction items in the front-end of the site. When a user visits url `www.somesite.com/auctions/2`, I want to display details of auction with id 2.

I have successfully written a .htaccess redirect that will get the id, so I can use the id to find the auction in the table and display its detail. But the problem not is that Wordpress displays 404 page if I visit that url.

This is what I have tried.

**.hatccess**

```
RewriteRule ^(auction)/(.*)$ ?action=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

So now if someone visits `/auction/1`, `var_dump(id)` will get me `1`. I have a `Auction` class for which I intend to get the respective auction by doing `$auction->get(id)` in my theme.

So far everything works fine, apart from the `404 page` I get when I visit the url. I have tried following to get rid of the `404 page` if someone visits the url.

```
// code below this point doesnt work as intended.

public function resolveURL(){
    global $wp_query;

    $action = $_GET['action'];
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    if($action == 'auction' && !empty($id)){

        status_header(200);
        $wp_query->is_page = $wp_query->is_singular = true;
        $wp_query->is_404  = false;
  }
}
```

And in my theme `base.php` i call:

```
  global $wppa; // plugin object
  $wppa->resolveURL();
```

I want to not get the 404 page when I call the function and the url is `/auction/someid`. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `var_dump($id)` should return `1` for `/auction/1`, no? You said it returns `2`. How are you seeing the result of `var_dump` if you're getting a 404 error for the URL?

Comment: oh sorry. I meant 1. I will edit it. I have a 404 page and the site gets redirected to it.

Comment: Where are you seeing the output of `var_dump`?

Comment: I have added it in the function `resolveURL()` after the if statement. Right above the `status_header(200)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized that 
    `status_header(200);` actually sets the status to 200. So I had to edit my `index.php` to check `is_404()` and do accordingly.

Comment: Hi - does this mean that actual 404's now are also returning 200 ? Assume you just want the custom template to not be 404.